# Cartthrob: How to allow checkout with zero shipping for collection but charged by weight for normal orders?

Tags: cartthrob, shipping, checkout

Using Cartthrob 4.6.2
I need to be able to allow a customer to select an option to make online payment as usual through the current gateway but select whether to be able to collect from store (which zeroes the shipping) or have the order shipped (which incurs the charges as set out in the 'by weight - threshold' shipping options)

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out aloud - could you set up a discount that gives free shipping then trigger that discount at whatever point you needed it. You can always revoke the discount for if the customer wants to go back to normal shipping.

Comment: The discount system can't differentiate between guests on the site so simply applies free shipping across the board. 
The other option is to use a coupon code that I hardwire into the checkout. I can do this using the add coupon form however in order for it to *actually* register the free shipping in the gateway this *has* to be within the checkout_form tag... and I'm not sure how I'd enable the toggle there...